# javascript_include_tag for admin section

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What's the best practice for storing and referencing JS for admin section of site?

Currently, I have an application.js that references a lot of JS (both vendor and app). I'd like to move some of the references into another file so it's not loaded (unnecessarily) when a user is not admin.

I'm looking for the following behavior:

1. If user is not admin, load everything in application.js including all files under `/assets/javascripts` via `//= require_tree .`
2. If user is admin, load everything that a regular user would load. In addition, load some specific JS. I'm not sure where to store the JS since I don't want it to be picked up by `require_tree`

Any suggestions on where to store the code, and how to call it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this. Create a `admin_application.js` file that requires all your `.js` code you need for the admin users, excluding the `require_tree` directive, and maintain an unchanged `application.js` that has all the requires and stuff for non-admin users.
If they share a common layout, it would be easy enough to put some logic inside your header tag to handle the two cases. Example:

**application.html.erb**

```
<header>
  <% if current_user.is_admin? %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "admin_application" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <% end %>
</header>
```

I think this is a easy and fair approach to your problem.

Comment: MurifoX, this don't work.
I have almost the same problem, and when you put a js in assets/javascript rails load it automatically. Is there a better sugestion to solve this issue? thnx

Comment: Should I keep the admin files in a separate directory? Should I call require tree within the non-admin JS?

Comment: It would only load **all** of your `.js` files on your assets/javascript folder if you put a `require_tree` on any javascript file that is being loaded on the layout page.

Comment: If you want more control, don't use the require_tree directive and manually require all of your needed javascript. This is error-prone but it works.